# webpack 2 cannot resolve empty extensions

Tags: javascript, webpack, migration, webpack-2

So in [webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org) when requiring/import a file `import file from './file';`

I got the following message:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

This is because when requiring a file in webpack@1.xx I used to have:

`resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  ...`

But it seems this is no longer accepted in webpack@2

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

I have read [migrating guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) but I couldn't find it.

My loaders are as simple as that:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: what do you have as your loaders? might help if you put the config file up.

Comment: yeah, please refer your config file so we can see what the problem is

Answer (score 9):

In a newer Webpack Version you can't use an empty string. It says:

`Getting error: configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty`.

You have to use `extensions: ['.js']` or `extensions: ['*', '.js']`.

Issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3043

Answer (score 5):

this has been modified now in webpack2

now you have to provide only

```
resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.ts','jsx','tsx']}
```

based upon the code syntax you choose

and if you provide '' in the array it throws an error

> configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty

you can also provide `['*']` if you want to match all files.